# Stored procedure sometimes takes a long time to execute query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have strange issue and I am getting more confused about this. I am using UWP on the .NET framework and using SQL Server as database. The problem is my application working too much slow and when I check my stored procedure execution time then I am notice that may be a problem is from the database stored procedure side.

My stored procedure sometimes takes 4-5 seconds to execute and sometimes takes more like 15-16 seconds and sometimes it takes more than 1 minute.

My questions are:

1. Why is it taking a lot more time sometimes, but not every time?
2. How can I solve this issue and boost my application execution time?

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNAME]  
    @HouseID INT,      
    @FromDate DATETIME,
    @ToDate DATETIME,   
    @PageNumber INT,
    @PageSize INT, 
    @RollID INT   
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RoomID INT = 0
    DECLARE @UnitID INT = 0
    DECLARE @HouseCode INT = 0
    DECLARE @StartRow INT
    DECLARE @EndRow INT

    SET @StartRow = @PageNumber 
    SET @StartRow = ((@StartRow-1) * @PageSize) + 1
    SET @EndRow = (@StartRow + @PageSize) - 1; 

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TableName') IS NOT NULL 
       DROP TABLE dbo.#TableName     

    SELECT 
        @HouseCode = [HouseCode],
        @UnitID = UnitId 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[tblHouse] 
    WHERE 
        [HouseId] = @HouseID   

    SELECT @RoomID = RoomCode 
    FROM [dbo].[tblUnit] u
    LEFT JOIN tblRoom h ON u.RoomID = h.Room 
    WHERE UnitID = @UnitID

    SELECT MAX(RoNum) RoNum 
    INTO dbo.#tableName 
    FROM [dbo].[TAbleNAme] 
    WHERE FanId = @HouseCode 
      AND InActive = 0
      AND ((InactivatedOn IS NULL AND StopDate IS NULL) 
           OR (ISNULL(InactivatedOn, StopDate) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate) 
           OR (ISNULL(InactivatedOn,StopDate) >= @ToDate)) 
      AND (FirstFillDate <= @ToDate)       
  GROUP BY 
      OrigRoNum

  SELECT 
      K.Topic, K.Comment, K.RoNum 
  INTO
      #TmptblRoCom 
  FROM 
      [dbo].[TableNAme] K
  LEFT JOIN 
      #TableName T ON K.RoNum = T.RoNum 
  WHERE 
      K.Topic = 'Nar Auto' 
      AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(K.Comment, 0, 3)) = 1 
      
  SELECT ButtonTypeID, ISNULL(SortOrder, 17) AS SortOrder 
  INTO dbo.#TableName
  FROM [dbo].[TAbleName] 
  WHERE NHID = @RoomID AND NHSortID = 29

  SELECT 
      DIN,
      'LU: ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ReasonCode)) + 
      'Exp:' + ISNULL(FORMAT(ExpiryDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'Indefinite') AS HLCode 
  INTO
      dbo.#TableName
  FROM
      [dbo].[TableNAme] 
  WHERE 
      PatID = @HouseCode 
      AND (ExpiryDate IS NULL OR ExpiryDate > GETDATE())

  SELECT 
      X.DgID AS DumbID,
      X.ID AS RID,
      CASE 
          WHEN DR.BandName IS NULL
              THEN '@' + dm.Description 
          ELSE CONCAT(BandName, ' ', strength) 
      END AS DugName,
      StrengthType, FormType,
      CASE 
          WHEN GericName IS NULL
              THEN
                  CASE 
                      WHEN BandName IS NULL 
                          THEN '@' + dm.Description 
                          ELSE CONCAT(DR.BandName, ' ', DR.strength) 
                  END 
              ELSE CONCAT(DR.GericName, ' ', DR.strengthTypr) 
      END AS GericName,
      DR.[Description],
      dbo.GetDirectionWithFullForm (X.IG,' ') AS Direction,
      CAST(X.RoNum AS BIGINT) AS RoNum,
      FORMAT(X.FirstFillDate,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS FirstFillDate,
      FORMAT(X.LastFillDate,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS DugOrderDate,
      ISNULL(TP.[ID],0) AS RollID,
      TP.[Cont] AS Cont,
      TP.[DisContinue] AS Disc,
      TP.[Hold] AS Hold,
      CAST(m.OrderType AS INT) AS OrderType,
      pl.HLCode,
      rc.Comment,
      TP.[Comments]
  FROM 
      dbo.#TAbleNAme  rn 
  INNER JOIN 
      [dbo].[RollRx] X ON rn.RoNum = X.RoNum           
  INNER JOIN 
      [dbo].[RollDg] DR ON X.[DgID] = DR.ID      
  LEFT JOIN 
      [dbo].[RollDgMix] DM ON X.MixID = DM.ID             
  LEFT JOIN 
      [dbo].[RollPreviousNumber] TP ON X.DrgID = TP.[RollMedicationID] 
                                    AND X.[ID] = TP.[RoID] 
                                    AND TP.[HouseID] = @HouseID 
                                    AND TP.[TableName] = @RollID
  LEFT JOIN 
      dbo.#TableNAme m ON m.TypeID = X.TypeID 
  LEFT JOIN 
      dbo.#TableName pl ON pl.DNNUM = X.DNNUM
  LEFT JOIN 
      dbo.#TableName rc ON rc.RoNum = X.RoNum
END
```

[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyvBIIFrc)

Comment: You are not dropping table  #TmptblRocom before inserting into it.  Could this be your problem?

Comment: monitor the database when you get the long execution times (resource waits, locks, memory, network, etc). You could/should also check if there are indexes/statistics needed looking at the execution plan (this is somewhat advanced yet very useful for those that can fully understand them). @JonathanWillcock comment in wrong question? This one has no INSERT statement.

Comment: @Cleptus Sorry you are right.  It is of course SELECT ... INTO  which does insert data :-)

Comment: That table is droped `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TableName') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#TableName `

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing, there is quite a lot of information how to solve that.

Comment: Could be bad parameter sniffing indeed. Check [this link](https://red9.com/blog/what-is-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/) to know what it is and how to detect it

Comment: Without execution plans it's really hard to say. Please share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Charlieface, I have shared execution plans

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the links

Comment: Don't forget that it could be also something else, like an update statement that's blocking your procedure.

Comment: It's hard to know where to start with such a complex query. But things that come to mind: Probably what's happening is parameter sniffing, or bad statistics. So the exact parameters or values used can make a big difference to the query, and with poor indexing the compiler will struggle to pick an optimal strategy, and may sometimes fall back to a bad plan (this happens when the query is recompiled, which happens on every run if you use temp tables). Why are you using temp tables at all? They will only be useful if you properly index them, and you are not. ....

Comment: .... The queries have some serious issues with non-indexed table scans and the like, so there is plenty of improvement. I would imagine that after fully indexing the various tables, performance would increase to the point the server would not have a problem choosing an optimal strategy.

Comment: That execution plan is totally different than the code pasted!

Answer (score 0):

Yes sounds like parameter sniffing or lack of memory issue (this has made it block for me at times when I am running to much on my box), look at the execution plan.

Run the stored proc with your parameters and see if there is a difference here, by right clicking on the execution plan select, below shows an example.

[image]

Comment: Can You please review my execution plan which I Updated with question and Help me solve issue.

Comment: Your plan seems different from what you orginally posted, for example there is TmptblRxCom which was not mentioned, this had 700,000+ rows in it! 
I cant help much really as that is a complex query, You could try adding some indexes, but that code is doing so much stuff. I would consider seeing If it can be reduced and simplified. If other people are calling this stored proc with different values then try what I show, but if is just the same parameter on your machine then maybe you have memory issue. Try and recreate the slowness and look at the live execution plan, that should show slowness